# Raise a Click event from ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

How to execute

```
document.getElementById("<%= btnHiddenBreak.ClientID%>").click()
```

using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`.

I am trying it like this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.Page, 
    Page.GetType(), 
    "OpenModalDialog", 
    "<script type=text/javascript>document.getElementById('<%= tnHiddenBreak.ClientID%>').click() ;</script>", 
    false);`
```

but it is throwing an error .

Asp code for the button is

```
<asp:Button id="btnHiddenBreak" runat="server" 
    Visible="false" 
    OnClientClick="openmodalWinBreak();" 
    OnClick="btnHiddenBreak_Click" />
```

The Error message which I am getting is :-

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The script tag
>   registered for type 'ASP.associates_home_aspx' and key
>   'OpenModalDialog' has invalid characters outside of the script tags:
>   document.getElementById('<%=
>   btnHiddenBreak.ClientID%>').click() ;. Only properly
>   formatted script tags can be registered.

Please guide me what the mistake I am doing and fix my code as per ..

Comment: I am a little confused with your code. You want to execute the `openmodalWinBreak()` with onClientClient event tats fine, why again the RegisterStartupScript? I dont think thats necessary

Comment: the more i read into your code, the more confused i am getting. whats your requirement? fire client click event when button is clicked? also, you want to pass some parameters into it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "OpenModalDialog", "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('" + btnHiddenBreak.ClientID + "').click() ;</script>", false);
```

Comment: You missed single quotes around the type attribute value: `type='text/javascript'`

Comment: @KrishanuDey: whats your script type?

Comment: @naveen : thanks dude. Due to my browser's problem the edit was not committed properly.

Comment: Thanks @krishanu and Yuriy, Now i can execute the script.

Answer (score 1):

For script tags, type='text/javascript' is the default, so the best solution is to exclude it. Better yet, exclude the script tag altogether and set the final parameter of RegisterStartupScript to true like so:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.Page, 
    Page.GetType(), 
    "OpenModalDialog", 
    "document.getElementById('<%=tnHiddenBreak.ClientID%>').click();", 
    true);
```